# How to sort a table in XlsxWriter using filter's 'Sort A to Z'?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Recently, I've discovered XlsxWriter for Python (and I do enjoy it!) and I started working on some spreadsheet. I need to programmatically create a spreadsheet identical to one created manually by some other person. I managed to create everything I needed except for sorting table in autofilter. Basically, I would like to create something like this:[image: Manually created autofiler]
and I couldn't figure out how. I checked with the documentation ([1](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?#worksheet-autofilter), [2](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_autofilters.html#working-with-autofilters)) and didn't find any information about sorting. What I do now is:

`worksheet.autofilter(1, 0, known_lenght, known_width)`

which results in autofilter arrow appearing in lower right corner of header cells but `worksheet.autofilter()` seems to lack sorting capability. Am I missing something or is there no option to create autofilter and set sorting in it in XlsxWriter? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Am I missing something or is there no option to create autofilter and set sorting in it in XlsxWriter?

Sorting of data in Excel is done at runtime and isn't a function of the file format. As such it isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

Instead you should sort the data in Python and then write it to the autofilter region.

However, that won't set the autofilter arrow to "sorted". That isn't currently supported in XlsxWriter.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to know:) Thank you for your answer and for developing XlsxWriter, it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Use xlsxwriter to sort and filter the columns and rows after unlocking all the cells in a password-protected sheet

```
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter

# Load the workbook and sheet
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/DEMO_I.xlsx")
sheet = workbook["DEMO_I"]

# Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet using XlsxWriter
output_file = "C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/DEMO_I_protected.xlsx"
workbook_xlsx = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file)
worksheet_xlsx = workbook_xlsx.add_worksheet()

# Copy data from existing worksheet to new worksheet
for row_num, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True), start=1):
    for col_num, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
        worksheet_xlsx.write(row_num - 1, col_num - 1, value)

# Set unlocked format for all cells
unlocked_format = workbook_xlsx.add_format({'locked': False})
worksheet_xlsx.protect("1234", options={'format_columns': True, 'autofilter': True, 'sort': True,
                   'select_locked_cells':False,'select_unlocked_cells':False,'delete_columns':False,
                   'insert_columns':False,'delete_rows':False,'format_cells':False,'format_rows':False})

# Apply autofilter to all columns
num_rows = sheet.max_row
num_cols = sheet.max_column
worksheet_xlsx.autofilter(0, 0, num_rows - 1, num_cols - 1)

# Apply sort to all columns
worksheet_xlsx.unprotect_range('A1:D12', 'MyRange')

# Save the XlsxWriter workbook
workbook_xlsx.close()
```